# SupportMapFragment Map is null

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, fragment

I am using following code to display a map in Xamarin.Android:

```
private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
private GoogleMap map;

protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            mapFragment = SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag ("map") as SupportMapFragment;
            if (mapFragment == null) {
                GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions ()
                    .InvokeCompassEnabled (true)
                    .InvokeMapType (GoogleMap.MapTypeNone)
                    .InvokeZoomControlsEnabled (false);

                FragmentTransaction frx = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
                mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.NewInstance (options);
                frx.Add (Resource.Id.map,mapFragment,"map");
                frx.Commit ();
            }


if (map == null)
                map = mapFragment.Map;

            CircleOptions circle = new CircleOptions ();
            circle.InvokeCenter (new LatLng(18.5203,73.8567));
            circle.InvokeRadius (1000);
            map.AddCircle (circle);
```

and my AXML is

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

After successful deployment on device, it is giving me an exception on line `map.AddCircle (circle);` as `System.NullReferenceException` has been thrown `Object Reference is not set to an instance of an Object`.

What am I doing wrong? Is there something needed to be initialized?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct layout?

Comment: ya I am using correct layout

Comment: @user3249477: Earlier it worked for me. But now same code is giving me exception.

Comment: The exception you're getting at map.AddCircle(circle) means that map == null. In the code prior to that you're checking for null on map and if it's null you do map = mapFragment.Map.

You don't check whether that isn't null though. So it's likely that both map and mapFragment.Map are null. And thus this code is giving you this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag ("map") as SupportMapFragment;
```

Should not work as you are trying to cast a `View` coming outside of `Mono.Android`. Hence you must use:

```
SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag<SupportMapFragment>("map");
```

or

```
SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag ("map").JavaCast<SupportMapFragment>();
```

Also you are trying to find a fragment by `Tag`. However, you didn't give your `Fragment` a `Tag` in your XML, so you need to find it by `Id` instead:

```
var mapFragment = SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById<SupportMapFragment>(Resource.Id.map);
```

Actually from the code you have pasted the line:

```
SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag ("map") as SupportMapFragment;
```

Will always be null, as you are actually ignoring the layout entirely, and you will always use the manually created `SupportMapFragment` in the `if (mapFragment == null)` condition...

Also, last time I checked, the bindings for the `FindFragmentByXXX` didn't support the generic type, so you will probably have to do the `JavaCast<T>();`

So, I would revise my code to look more like:

```
private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
private GoogleMap map;

protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);

    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

    SetUpMapIfNeeded();
}

public override void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();
    SetUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void SetUpMapIfNeeded()
{
    if(null != map) return;

    mapFragment = SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.map).JavaCast<SupportMapFragment>();
    if (mapFragment != null)
    {
        map = mapFragment.Map;

        if (map == null)
        {
            // throw error here, should never happen though...
            return;
        }

        // set up map here, i.e.:
        map.UiSettings.CompassEnabled = true;
        map.MapType = GoogleMap.MapTypeHybrid;
        map.MyLocationChange += MapOnMyLocationChange;

        CircleOptions circle = new CircleOptions ();
        circle.InvokeCenter (new LatLng(18.5203,73.8567));
        circle.InvokeRadius (1000);
        map.AddCircle (circle);
    }
}
```